# How do injuries play into the final fight in Creed III (2023)?

Tags: plot-explanation, creed-iii

In the third act of *Creed III*, Donnie Creed (Michael B Jordan) challenges Damian Anderson (Jonathan Majors) to a title fight. Creed and his trainer are shown cataloging Creed's lifetime of injuries — broken fingers, snapped ribs, concussions, etc. They note that Anderson will know all of these and exploit them. Indeed, he had exploited the injuries of another fighter earlier in the film, killing him, and is shown reviewing tapes of Creed's boxing, looking for weaknesses. "You need to turn these weaknesses into strengths," Creed's trainer tells him.

This carefully established fighting tactic is never mentioned again. In the inevitable 'this is a Rocky movie' training montage that follows, the weaknesses are not addressed or turned into strengths. In the climactic fight, Anderson never exploits Creed's injuries. Creed never uses them as strengths.

Did I miss something?